# Blazor: Problems with namespaces when same term is used before and after a dot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I've a problem with Blazor when I have different projects having namespaces with the same term on different side of the dot(s), in my example **frontend.project** and **project.data**:

What I did:

- Create a new solution with a **blazor** serverside project named **frontend.project**
- Add a new class library, named **project.data**
- On frontend.project, add reference to project.data
- Open _Import.razor on frontend.project, add **@using project.data**

I'm getting the error:
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'data' does not exist in the namespace 'frontend.project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

adding @using project.data inside a .razor-file results in the same error

Also intellisense shows that the namespace is searched in frontend.project, despite having @using project.data:

[image]

on .cs / .cshtml.cs files, everything works fine as expected, only .razor-files are affected.

Tried on Visual Studio 16.7.7 / .NET 3.1.403

Here's a demo project on GitHub: https://github.com/Sabbi/blazor-namespace-issue

Any ideas how how to solve this without renaming the namespaces?

Comment: @Vencovsky the order of the using does not change anything - even with only `@using project.data` in _Imports.razor (or any other .razor-File), the error persists.

Comment: The current project namespace project conflicts with the namespace of project.data.

Answer (score -1):

Try right-clicking your solution file in the Solution Explorer and press 'Sync Namespaces'.